# Reason for different speeds of floating point division with and without opt.flag -O3 (C++/C)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, floating-point

I was trying to measure the speed difference of single precision division vs double precision division in C++

Here is the simple code that I have written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  float     f_x = 45672.0;
  float     f_y = 67783.0;
  double    d_x = 45672.0;
  double    d_y = 67783.0;

  float     f_answer;
  double    d_answer;

  clock_t   start,stop;
  int       N = 200000000 //2*10^8


 start = clock();
 for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    f_answer = f_x/f_y;
  }
 stop = clock();
 std::cout<<"Single Precision:"<< (stop-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"    "<<f_answer <<std::endl;


start = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    d_answer = d_x/d_y;
  }
stop = clock();
std::cout<<"Double precision:" <<(stop-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"   "<< d_answer<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

When I compiled the code without optimization as `g++ test.cpp` I got the following output

```
Desktop: ./a.out
Single precision:8.06    0.673797
Double precision:12.68   0.673797
```

But if I compile this with `g++ -O3 test.cpp` then I get

```
Desktop: ./a.out
Single precision:0    0.673797
Double precision:0   0.673797
```

How did I get such a drastic performance increase? The time being shown in the second case is 0 because of the low resolution of the `clock()` function. Did the compiler somehow detect that each for loop iteration is independent of the previous iterations?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a performance test the optimizer can't optimize out of existence. It uses complex numbers, so each simple operation on the complex number involves multiple multiplies, adds and subtracts of the underlying data type.

Comment: In stead of hard coding the values, read it a run time and see the difference, What I am guessing is compiler optimized and calculated the values at compile time itself

Comment: @user430294: Even if you read the values at run-time, the compiler is going to notice that they never change during the loop and optimize the loop down to one 'iteration'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the assembly that you get from `g++ -O3 -S`, it's quite apparent the loops and all of your floating point calculations (aside from those involving the time) were optimized out of existence:

```
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB970:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        .cfi_offset 3, -24
        subq    $24, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
        call    clock
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        call    clock
        movq    %rax, %rbp
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        subq    %rbx, %rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

See the two calls to `clock`, one right after the other? And before those, only some stack maintenance instructions. Yep, those loops are completely gone.

You only use `f_answer` or `d_answer` to print out an answer that can be trivially calculated at compile time, and the compiler can see that. There's no point in even having them. And if there's no point in having them, there's no point in having `f_x`, `f_y`, `d_x`, or `d_y` either. All gone.

To solve this, you need to have each iteration of the loop depend on the results from the last iteration. Here is my solution to this problem. I use the `complex` template to do some calculations involved in calculating the Mandlebrot set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <complex>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using ::std::complex;
   using ::std::cout;

   const complex<float> f_coord(0.1, 0.1);
   const complex<double> d_coord(0.1, 0.1);

   complex<float> f_answer(0, 0);
   complex<double> d_answer(0, 0);

   clock_t   start, stop;
   const unsigned int N = 200000000; //2*10^8

   start = clock();
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
      f_answer = (f_answer * f_answer) + f_coord;
   }
   stop = clock();
   cout << "Single Precision: " << (stop-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
        << "    " << f_answer << '\n';


   start = clock();
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
      d_answer = (d_answer * d_answer) + d_coord;
   }
   stop = clock();
   cout << "Double precision: " <<(stop-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
        << "   " << d_answer << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Omnifarious for the answer. I ran your code, and strangely enough the double precision calculation is outperforming the single precision calculation(with and without optimizations). e.g. With optimization I get Single Precision calculation to be `2.33` seconds and double precision calculation to be `0.99` seconds? How is that? I would have thought single precision calculations would be faster.

Comment: @smilingbuddha: I am not overly surprised. I wouldn't be surprised to discover that your numbers are being converted to doubles to do the calculations and then back to floats again for storage. Some CPUs have fp registers that are 128 bits long and that's just that.

With gcc, you might try the `-march=native` and `-mtune=native` options. It might be that gcc is choosing poor fp operations for your architecture.

Answer (score 7):

Probably because the compiler optimised the loop away to a single iteration.  It may even have done the division at compile-time.

Check the assembler of your executable to be sure (use e.g. objdump).

Comment: Better yet, it ought to evaluate the expression value at compile time.

Comment: Better yet, there is no reason to evaluate any floating point expressions at all. The results are never used anywhere. I wouldn't be surprised if the loop were optimized down to a simple counter. gcc doesn't optimize loops out of existence, as a general rule, because it makes it much harder to write timing loops.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yeah, I noticed. That's a change in behavior, though from how long ago I don't remember. I remember a detailed rationale being given for why they weren't going to do this that I thought only sort of made sense. So, generally I'm happy with the change, but it is a change.

Comment: I don't see how optimizing loops out of existence could make it harder to write a timing loop...

Comment: @R..: Because a common timing loop was, at one point, 'increment a counter until it gets to a particular value, then ignore the value the counter got to'. That optimizes down to nothing if the optimizer is doing really well.

Comment: That kind of timing loop is so broken it's not even worth considering. It was obsolete the day people started writing programs that run on more than a single fixed-spec machine. Do you remember having to hit the "turbo" button on your 386 to slow it down like an old 8086 to get it to play your games at the right speed? Yeah. Not cool...

Comment: @R..: Well, Linux still has the 'bogomips' measure which is used for calibrating those kinds of timing loops. I agree with you, but I also think that in some cases it can be hard to do better.

Comment: I can't think of many (any) places where this ugly hackery would work better than a proper sleep or a busy loop that *actually reads the current time* and terminates when a given time is reached.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `volatile` qualifier in the definitions of your floats and doubles, the compiler won't optimize away the unused calculations.

Comment: That would work, but it would hamstring the optimizer in certain ways. And I think one of the points is to discover if the optimizer, when allowed to do its job normally, produces code in which there's much of a time difference between floats and doubles.